# Wsdl Parsing in ios

Tags: ios, web-services, wsdl

Can any one help me how to consume WCF services in an iPhone application? 
I am searching it desperately. I have also installed the wsdl2objc from http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/. but still I am not getting any clue that How can I use it to worth get the correct responce.

Please get me out of this trouble...I need the right solution!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are about to use the SOAP services than my advice is don't.....because for SOAP services you may able to construct the base classes using http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/ but the response you will get from the service will give the references and the whole data structures along with response and you can't parse the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this wonderful framework called [CSOAP](http://csoap.sourceforge.net/)