# Call WSDL using REST Api in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, wsdl, restkit

I have WSDL url with me. I have two methods in the WSDL, I need to access those method and get response using REST api.

What I have tried is below?

I used the below code snippets for request and response. But I didnt get any response.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURLNSURL :          [URLWithString"https://mywebsite.com/service.svc?wsdl"]];
        [request setHTTPMethod"IBillingSubmissionService_RegisterDevice_InputMessage"];                                                               
        NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [myConnection start];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
        [dataWebService setLength:0];
    }

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        NSLog(@"Response: %@",data);

        [dataWebService appendData:data];
    }

    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"Response: %@",responseString);



    }

              - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
                  NSLog(@"Eror during connection: %@", [error description]);
    }
```

What ever I am doing above is correct? Can some one provide a sample code snippet to call and get response using REST?

I want to know the below:

1) How to pass the value to WSDL method?

2) How to pass a reqiest and get response?

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly use the wsdl webservices in objective c but you have to first construct the reference base classes.

You can use [wsdl2objc](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) code generator to construct the base classes to call the wsdl webservice

and Please refer the [usage instructions](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions) for how to use it.

UPDATE: As a my advice you can see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626451/wsdl-parsing-in-ios/17883082#17883082)